# Facebook/Google Social Login via HTTP Request

Tags: auth0, flutter

Social providers authenticate users passively (i.e: you open their login page and get redirected after login to a redirect uri you specify that contains the login token or failure message).

How can I:
1. launch the authentication request to a social providers uri from within flutter.
2. after login success/failure read the response from the redirect uri provided as part of the login request.

Answer (score 1):

For Facebook, you can open a browser with the [url_launcher](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/url-launcher) plugin. Check out this post: [Facebook Oauth login flow with Flutter](https://medium.com/@segaud.kevin/facebook-oauth-login-flow-with-flutter-9adb717c9f2e).

For Google Sign-In, there's a [google_sign_in plugin](https://github.com/flutter/google_sign_in) that will let you authenticate with the native Google Sign-In SDK.

Comment: Thank you, these seem like viable options. I just filed a bug on the flutter github for google_sign_in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9951, there seems to be a build issue when running the latest version of flutter.

Answer (score 0):

You may also rely on Firebase Auth Plugins :
https://github.com/flutter/firebase_auth

Thanks @collin